# change database date format permanently

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

as currently the default date format in Oracle is dd-MON-yy :

```
10-SEPT-17
```

I would like to change the Oracle date format setting permanently to Monddyyyy hh12:mi:ss pm , this due to the legacy program sql insert statement were written in such way, hence i would like to change the format example as below :

```
SEPT102017 06:52:00 pm
```

I've tried with alter sessions, however it doesn't work on my application sql, kindly advise which method able to do that

Comment: The approach is wrong. It is not up to the database to adapt to the SQL of your application, but the opposite. Changing the default date format will more then probably create side-issues. Change your SQL and use TO_DATE() function on all datetime operations.

Comment: You can also set default values on your client by Environment variables and/or Registry settings.

Comment: Please show your code. If ALTER SESSION does not work then you have an issue with your code

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I would like to set the system default date format as that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use `ALTER SYSTEM` (as per [BA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46645018/1509264)), you can create a logon trigger to change the session parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHANGE_DATE_FORMAT
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
CALL DBMS_SESSION.SET_NLS('NLS_DATE_FORMAT','"MONDDYYYY HH12:MI:SS AM"')
/
```

Comment: Pick your answer as better approach as its better and easier to manage compared to Alter SYSTEM which is difficult to migrate/ configure for new environment

Answer (score 3):

You can change it on the session using the command

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='Monddyyyy hh12:mi:ss'
```

However, if you are unable to do that from within your application, you can change it by changing the system default

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='Monddyyyy hh12:mi:ss' scope=both
```

Comment: I would like to use the Alter system, however i got this specified initialization parameter is not modifiable with this option. is there any other approach to change the system default date format?

Comment: Usually this parameter can be set using `alter system`. Have a look at this post for changing spfile using pfile:    http://www.orafaq.com/node/5